# Is replying to a promotional question with a promotional answer breaking the promotional rule?

Tags: discussion, rules

In this question:
[Looking to increase my iMac's RAM](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323319/looking-to-increase-my-imacs-ram/323320?noredirect=1#comment412418_323320)

The OP states:

> I found one on the Apple website, but it is $400. If I could find a better price, it would be amazing.

Clearly looking for a place where he can find RAM for a good price.

In response I included in my answer:

> You can also purchase at great prices from them [A website a provided earlier in the answer].

2 people asked for that to be removed saying it was promotional. I replied with the reasoning above. I thought that I should ask on Meta as I was unsure if I had broken the rule against promotional answers/questions.

It does appear that the community agrees as they have upvoted my answer 6 times and my explanation comment 7 times.

I would just like some clarification.

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! And thanks for seeking feedback here as it helps other users too.

This can be a tricky issue because it's often subjective (and therefore users are influenced by their personal experience, feelings, tastes, or opinions).

In this case, the question itself *could* have been closed on a number of grounds but obviously the community didn't think it quite crossed the line, so it still stands. To my mind you've answered the question and the community by and large has agreed by the number of votes your answer has received.

So, in a nutshell, you haven't *broken* any promotional rules.

However, to help reduce the risk of users judging an answer as being promotional, users can take some steps. Using your answer as an *example*, users can:

- **Be less emotive.** So, instead of *"You can also purchase at great prices from them."* it may be better to say something like *"Generally they offer competitive prices."*
- **Use a clear disclaimer.** Have a clear disclaimer that declares your interest, if any, when referring to a product, service, website etc. Something like *"**Note:** This is not promotional just trying to provide a site."* is not as clear as something like *"**Note:** I have no affiliation with..."* or ***"Note:*** I happen to work at..."
- **Offer multiple recommendations.** Where possible, provide more than one choice so that it's less likely to be judged as purely promoting a particular product, service or website. If you've only used one personally, you can specify that so it's clear you haven't used the others.

As I said this is often a subjective topic. Some things are very clearly promotional (or even SPAM), but others can be caught up in that grey area of uncertainty.

Comment: For anyone wanting to add more steps that users can take, feel free to edit this answer. :)

Comment: I will edit my answer accordingly. I think all 3 suggestions are extremely helpful. And thanks for the explanation. I do agree, in this case, that the community agrees with your (and my) opinion, but obviously some people will disagree, hopefully the suggestions will help these people understand a bit more.